# Improving data on row

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have `N` rows (which could be nothing less than 1000) on an excel spreadsheet. And in this sheet our project has 150 columns like this:

[image]

Now, our application needs data to be copied (using normal `Ctrl+C`) and pasted (using `Ctrl+V`) from the excel file sheet on our GUI sheet. I have increased by using Divide and Conquer or some other mechanism. Currently i am not really sure how to go about this. Here is what part of my code looks like:

The above code gets called row-wise like this:

Please know my question needs a more algorithmic solution than code optimization, however any answers containing code related optimizations will be appreciated as well. (Tagged `Linq` because although not seen i have been using linq in some parts of my code).

Comment: You should tag a question with tags directly related to the code in the post or if you expect answers to require the tag as part of the solution.  Its fine if you want LINQ in the answer, just don't use the tag because you use the technology in a way unrelated to the question or answer.  I left the LINQ tag because LINQ may be an appropriate way to address the question.  I also added EXCEL because the code appears to use excel interop.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to find out where the slowest part of this process is? This looks like it might be possible to split up the rows and parallelize the validation. This might require some metadata to put it all back together correctly, but from what little you have here, it appears this problem may be able to benefit from such parallelization.

Comment: I have already shown the piece of code taking most time. Is this the best SO can do? :( Not got an answer....

Comment: @Lohit, Which piece of code is it that's taking "most" time? I'd love to help, but your question is very unclear. You've posted a lot of text, but not a whole lot of clearly relevant information. Additionally, your posted code references "mystery" functions -- functions which could have the bottlenecks in them. Nobody can optimize an algorithm they can't see.

Comment: I know, i may be a little bit off the topic, but i wonder, if is it possible for you to do validation not at the and, but while inserting a row, and saving that validation results with that row, so that you don't have to validate them while selecting them.

Comment: You really need to profile your code, as Twanos says, so you know which bits to optimize first. Your code is unclear too. Are `CurRow` and `iRowIndex` the same?

Comment: Also, what is `dtValidateAndFormatConditions`? Is it a set of "rules" that your data must conform to? But you appear to be updating it, which seems strange.

Comment: And whats in `GetValidatedFormattedData(..)`?  That seems like it would be pretty important to your performance.

Comment: A few ideas to consider... 1.  Only validate a permutation once. - If your data has a lot of rows that are the same, you might be able to improve perf by implementing a 'validated' / 'unvalidated' set to compare rows against.  2.  Consider validation at the database layer.  It is likely faster and relies less on client computing resources.

Comment: @IntStarFoo: it can be faster on single client, but what a reason to have a server for single client?

Answer (score 6):

**1.** IIRC `dRow["Condition"]` is much slower than `dRow[index]` as it has to do a lookup every time. Find out which indexes the columns have before the call.

```
public virtual void ValidateAndFormatOnCopyPaste(DataTable DtCopied, int CurRow, int conditionIndex, int valueIndex)
{
    foreach (DataRow dRow in dtValidateAndFormatConditions.Rows)
    {
         string Condition = dRow[conditionIndex];
         string FormatValue = Value = dRow[valueIndex];
         GetValidatedFormattedData(DtCopied,ref Condition, ref FormatValue ,iRowIndex);
         Condition = Parse(Condition);
         dRow[conditionIndex] = Condition;
         FormatValue = Parse(FormatValue );
         dRow[valueIndex] = FormatValue;
    }
}
```

**2.** If you are updating a excel document live, you should also lock the sheet updates during the process, so the document isn't redrawn on every cell change.

**3.** `virtual` methods also have a performance penalty.

Comment: 2000 rows isn't that much really. It should be reasonable fast. But as you don't provide enough information about what you use to modify the document (or how) it's almost impossible to give specific suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer to a problem like this is you want to move as much as possible of the heavier processing out of the row loop, so it only needs to execute once instead of for every row.

It's difficult to provide more detail without knowing exactly how your validation/formatting system works, but I can offer some "pointers":

- Is it possible to build some kind of cached data structure from this condition table of yours?  This would eliminate all the heavy DataTable operations from your inner loop
- The most efficient solution to mass validation/formatting I can think of, is to construct a C# script based upon your set of conditions, compile it into a delegate and then just evaluate for each row.  I don't know if this is possible for your problem ...

Answer (score 1):

There are two proposed improvements in the algorithm : -

a.U can use multithreading if possible to speed the process by constant factor(need 
    testing to get the actual value). U can use multithreading to evaluate the rows in 
    parallel.

b. If it is possible to stop processing row if even one column is invalid then u can    stop 
     processing that row . Further u can analyse the input data for large no of data and 
     arrange the columns in decreasing porbabilty of them being invalid and then check for 
     columns in this calculated order. Further more u can also arrange the predicates of 
     validation condition in the way u did for columns for checking validations

Proposed algorithm which might improve performance: -

```
for i in totalconds :
   probability(i) = 0

for record in largeDataSet : 
    for col in record : 
        for cond in conditions :
            if invalid(cond,col) : 
               probability(cond)++

sort(probability(cond),condorder,order=decreasing)
```

check for condition in order of condorder

This is learning algorithm which can be used to calculate the order of evaluation of predicates for efficient short-circuit evaluation of conditions but would take same time for valid inputs. You can evaluate this order offline on large dataset of sample inputs and just store in array during live usage.

**Edit:** Another Improvement that i missed is that use of hash table for columns which have a small range of valid values , so instead of evaluating the conditions on that column we just check if it is in hash table. Similarly if invalid values range is small then we check for them in hash table. The hash table can be filled up at before the start of evaluation using a file.

Answer (score 0):

Operations like 'string Condition = dRow["Condition"]' are rather heavy, thus I would recommend to move row enumeration (for-cycle) from the ValidateAndFormat method to the ValidateAndFormatOnCopyPaste method, immediately around the call of GetValidatedFormattedData.

Comment: Err.. could please have a look at the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Pre steps:

- create a task class that accepts 1 dataRow and processes it
- create a task queue
- create a thread pool with Y workers

Algorithm

1. when you get your N rows, add all of them as tasks to your task queue
2. get the workers to start taking tasks from the task queue
3. as the tasks responses get returned, update your data table (probably initially a clone)
4. once all the tasks are done return your new data table

Possible Improvements

- as Vikram said, you could probably short circuit your conditions, if at value 10, you know that its already an error, don't bother checking the rest of the 140 conditions, but thats only if that fits your requirements, if your requirements require a  checked condition for all 150, then you can't escape that one
- change the task classes to take in a list of row data instead of 1, which could improve due to context switching between threads, if they finish pretty quickly

Other ideas that I haven't really thought through

- sort the data first, maybe there is a speed benefit with short circuiting certain known conditions
- checksum the whole row, store it into a db with its result, essentially cache the parameters/results so that the next time something with the exact same values/fields runs you can pull it from cache
- the other checksum of the whole row buys you is change, lets say that you have some sort of key and you are looking for changed data, the checksum of everything but the key will tell you if some value changed and if its even worth looking at the conditions of all the other columns

Comment: your answer seems to be most promising - could you please elaborate more on to exactly how can create a task class and task queue. This will require a bit of explanation preferably with some code.

Comment: take a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datatable.
try this 
datatable.Select(string.Format("[Col1] = '{0}'", id)).ToList().ForEach(r => r["Col1"] = Data);
see the link 
https://msinternal1.engageexpress.com/sf/MTY1NDNfMTY4NTM4

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of brute force, but you can combine it with what others have suggested:

```
Parallel.ForEach(dtValidateAndFormatConditions.Rows, dRow =>
        {
             string Condition = dRow[conditionIndex];
             string FormatValue = Value = dRow[valueIndex];
             GetValidatedFormattedData(DtCopied,ref Condition, ref FormatValue ,iRowIndex);
             Condition = Parse(Condition);
             FormatValue = Parse(FormatValue);
             lock (dRow)
             {
                 dRow[conditionIndex] = Condition;
                 dRow[valueIndex] = FormatValue;
             }
        });
```